# Find the minimum of a function

Tags: calculus

As you will see, $f(x,y)$ can be explicitly found. But how to find the min-max of the three parameters?

Let $f(x,y)=\max\{|x-y|,|x+y|,|x-2|\}$. How to find its minimum?

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{For all } x,y \text{ we have }  |x|+|y| \ge  \max (|x+y|,|x-y|)$$ $$\text{and } |x|+|y| \in \{|x+y|,|x-y|\}$$ $$\text{so }  \max (|x+y|,|x-y|)=|x|+|y|$$  $$ \text{so } f(x,y) =\max (|x|+|y|,|x-2|).$$ $$\text{Therefore }   x>1 \implies f(x,y)\ge |x|+|y|\ge |x|>1=f(1,0).$$ $$\text{And }  x<1 \implies f(x,y)\ge |x-2|>1=f(1,0). $$ $$\text{And }  x=1 \implies f(x,y)= \max (1+|y|,1) \ge 1$$  $$\text{with equality only when }  y=0.$$ So $\min f(x,y)=1$ and the minimum occurs only at $(x,y)=(1,0)$.